# Reuse Menu.ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, templates

I have created the following menu. Now I want to use the same menu layout on a different window and thought about shifting the below code to the Generic.xaml and only reference it, whenever I need it. What is the best way to do it, so that the actual usage is as short as possible?

```xml
<MenuHeight="27"VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Menu}">
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Menu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}" />
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                </Style>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemTemplate>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place this in the resources and it will be applied to every Menu in scope:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}" />
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Execute}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}" />
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
                    </Style>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemContainerStyle>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```